# matrix inversion within a function optimization problem

Tags: matrices, optimization

$$f(X)=diag(X)(XX^H+Y)^{−1}diag(X)^H$$ 
$X∈C^{N\times N}$ is a diagonal matrix.
$diag(X) \in C^{1\times N}$ is the diagonal of X.
$Y\in R^{N\times N}$ is a symmetric real matrix.
$H$ is the conjugate transpose.

I want to know how to maximize this function $f(X)$ with regard to $X$.

Comment: Is $Y$ required to be positive semi definite?  Or is $Y = -I$ allowed, say?

Comment: In fact Y is a covariance matrix, hence it is a positive semi definite one. @kimchilover

Answer (score 0):

For $X$ whose diagonal entries are non-zero, write $XX^H+Y = X(I+X^{-1}YX^{-H})X^H$.  Then $f(X) = u (I+X^{-1}YX^{-H})^{-1} u^H$, where $u$ is a vector all of whose entries are $1$.  The eigenvalues of $X^{-1}YX^{-H}$ are non-negative, so $X^{−1}YX^{−H}=Q\Lambda Q^H$ where $Q$ is unitary  and $\Lambda$ diagonal with non-negative entries. 
 So $f(X)= v (I+\Lambda)^{-1}v^H$, where $v=Q^H u$ has length $\sqrt N.$ The value $N$ is approached as all the entries of $X$ tend to $\infty$ and so finally $f(X)\le N$.  The value $N$ is approached if all the entries of $X$ tend to $\infty$, for which $\Lambda\to  0.$

I don't think the possibility of $0$ entries in $X$ will help beat this.

Comment: But what if $X$ is limited in power, $$E\{\Sigma_{i,j}|x_{i,j}|^2 \} = a$$ where $E$ is the expectation@KimchiLover

Comment: If you want to change important details of your problem, such as by introducing randomness where there was none before, or allowing diagonal matrices to have non-zero off diagonal entries, ask a new question.